# how to use a character as a function definition in R

Tags: r, function, character

I have lots of characters those are actually function definitions. How can I use that characters to execute those function?
The characters I have is as follows:

```
foo1 <- "function(p1,p2){, v <- 2, print(\"value is \"), print(v)}"

foo2 <- "function(){, cName <- .Call(\"companyNames\"), return(cName)}"

foo3 <- "function(tickers,field,date){,df<-data.frame(Ticker = tickers, Field = field, Date = date), return(df)}"
```

...etc

I need a general method to execute to all these functions.

Comment: This question is really unclear. Do you have a character string `foo <- "function(p1,p2){, v <- 2, print(\"value is \"), print(v)}"` which you want to parse into a function? Or are you trying to create a function which returnes `value is 2`?

Comment: actually what i need is to parse that character into a function. I have several characters like this. I need a general method to solve this problem.

Comment: Given your comment on the answer below, It is entirely unclear what you want, if the answer below is not the correct one.

Comment: You've edited your post, do you want all these functions called with no arguments?

Comment: The problem with all your function strings are that they are not valid R code. You have commas where `;` should be used to define an end of statement.

Comment: @sebastian-c: no.i want to call all these functions with same parameters mentioned in that character.

Comment: @DinoopNair So do you expect to get those parameters from? A list? The global environment?

Comment: @mnel:How can i change comma to ; of the function body?

Comment: Write correct r code? At the moment you have character strings. Where did you get these from?

Comment: @DinoopNair Are you reading all these functions from a text file? If so, maybe you should try `source('file.txt')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### EDIT: You've changed your question, so I've amended my answer:

```
do.call(eval(parse(text=foo1)), list())
```

You can add a named list to each of those functions in the place of `list()`. But frankly, what you're attempting is bordering on the absurd. I have no idea how you got into a position where you would need these kinds of tools. You're going to have all kinds of scoping problems from here on in.

#### Old solution:

```
fun <- eval(parse(text="function(p1,p2){v <- 2; print(paste0(\"value is \", v))}"))
fun()
## [1] "value is 2"
```

Comment: But in all honesty, I question why you would want to do this. I refer you to the following: `library(fortunes); fortune(106)`.

Comment: actually what i need is to parse that character into a function. I have several characters like this. I need a general method to solve this problem.

Comment: @DinoopNair: This answer *does* parse the character string and turns it into a function: `fun` is a function that you can call. You need to edit your question so it's more clear what you actually want.

Comment: @sebastian-c: this solution is almost correct. But the problem is because of the comma where ; is expected. How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: @sebastian-c ,Marius,mnel -  I removed commas from that character. Now i am getting the correct output. Thank you for helping me.